# python find() acting weird?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to grab the src from an image tag string, but it will not output anything.

```
image = '<img class="obitimgcenter" 
src="https://www.heritagefuneral.com/wp- 
content/uploads/2019/03/3427425.jpg" height="130px" 
width="130px">'
image = image[image.find('src="')+1:image.find('"')]
print(image)
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Did you try isolating the find calls into their own statements so you can see what they returned?

Comment: First one will return this --> rc="https://www.heritagefuneral.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/3427425.jpg" height="130px" width="130px">

Comment: so it is not grabbing the    rc="    and I have no idea why it wouldn't?

Comment: You mean the first one _did_ return the index you showed? Or you thought it sound but didn't?

Comment: `image.find('"')` is finding the *first* double-quote in the string, of course - which is before the `src=`, so you end up with an empty slice.  You'd need to use the optional second parameter to `.find()`, which specifies a starting position.

Comment: try something like this: `image = image[image.find('src="')+5:][:image[image.find('src="')+5:].find('"')]`

Comment: Anyway, for the second index you're finding the first " in the string from the beginning,  not the first one after the other thing you found. Doing each step separately should make it easier to see what's going on, and to write code that checks whether your assumptions are correct.

Comment: thanks @aminsaffar that worked! And I get it now I was grabbing the first instance of ' " '

Comment: Why are you using string functions instead of an HTML parser like Beautiful Soup?

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to do it in one line. Find the start:

```
start = image.find('src="') + 5
```

Then find the end using an argument for `find`'s start parameter to tell it where to start looking.

```
end = image.find('"',start)
```

Use those in a slice

```
print(image[start:end])
```

---

If you are parsing more html you might want to consider using BeautifulSoup.

```
In [23]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [24]: soup = BeautifulSoup(image,"html.parser")

In [25]: img = soup.find('img')

In [26]: img.attrs
Out[26]: 
{'class': ['obitimgcenter'],
 'height': '130px',
 'src': 'https://www.heritagefuneral.com/wp- \ncontent/uploads/2019/03/3427425.jpg',
 'width': '130px'}

In [27]: img['src']
Out[27]: 'https://www.heritagefuneral.com/wp- \ncontent/uploads/2019/03/3427425.jpg'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for this

```
image = '''<img class="obitimgcenter" src="https://www.heritagefuneral.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/3427425.jpg" height="130px" width="130px">'''

start_index = image.find('src="') #start index of src=
src_str_len = len('src="') # how long the search string is
end_index = image.find('"', start_index + src_str_len) #start searching from start_index + src_str_len
image = image[start_index:end_index]
print(image)
```

Answer (score -1):

This code will properly extract the value of src

```
image = '<img class="obitimgcenter" src="https://www.heritagefuneral.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/3427425.jpg" height="130px" width="130px">'

token = 'src="'
start = image.find(token) + len(token)
end = image.find('"', start)
image = image[start:end]

print(image)
```

You must add on offset to the start so you exclude the `src="` from your result, and you must use that offset start as the starting point when `find`ing the closing quote, or else you will just find an earlier quote in the string, resulting in an end index *after* your starting index, and a zero length string